# How do I serialize CharSequence to JSON with Play 2.1 and Scala

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework-2.1

I'm having trouble serializing a class that uses CharSequence instead of String. When I use Strings everything works fine.

I have the following class:

```
case class Word(word: CharSequence,
            meanings: Traversable[CharSequence],
            readings: Traversable[CharSequence]) {
}
```

When I try to serialize it as so:

```
...
val word = new Word("dog", List("Foo", "Goo"), List("Ba", "Fa"))
implicit val wordWrites = Json.writes[Word]
Ok(Json.toJson(word)).as(JSON)
```

I get the following error:

```
error: exception during macro expansion:
scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: No implicit Writes for CharSequence, Traversable[CharSequence], Traversable[CharSequence] available.
at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$class.inferImplicit(Typers.scala:55)
at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Typers$class.inferImplicitValue(Typers.scala:38)
at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Context.inferImplicitValue(Context.scala:6)
at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.Context.inferImplicitValue(Context.scala:6)
at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl$$anonfun$15.apply(JsMacroImpl.scala:332)
at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl$$anonfun$15.apply(JsMacroImpl.scala:317)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl$.writesImpl(JsMacroImpl.scala:317)
implicit val wordWrites = Json.writes[Word]
```

I understand that the authors of the serialization framework probably forgot to support CharSequence. However, how do I give the serializer a sensible default to call .toString() on all CharSequence instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a CharSequence Format:

```
implicit var csFormat = new Format[CharSequence] {
  def writes(c: CharSequence): JsValue = Json.toJson(c.toString)
  def reads(jv: JsValue): JsResult[String] = JsSuccess(Json.stringify(jv))
}

val word = new Word("dog", List("Foo", "Goo"), List("Ba", "Fa"))
implicit val wordWrites = Json.format[Word]
Ok(Json.toJson(word)).as(JSON)
```

Comment: I was hoping for some way to just configure a mapping that could be shared across many classes.

Comment: I love removing code, that's why I edited my answer so only the second and final solution remains.